# Fourier series of $|\sin{x}|$ in $(-\pi,\pi),$ questions regarding $L.$

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I'm tasked to find the Fourier series of $f(x)=|\sin{x}|$ in $(-\pi,\pi)$.

The period of $f$ is clearly $\pi$ since $|\sin(x+\pi)|=|\sin(x)|.$ So we set $2L=\pi\Leftrightarrow L=\pi/2.$ Since this is an even function we know that $b_n=0.$ For $a_0$ we use the formula

$$a_0=\frac{1}{L}\int\limits_{-L}^{L}f(x)dx\tag1$$

we have that

$$a_0=\frac{2}{\pi}\int\limits_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}|\sin(x)|dx=\frac{4}{\pi}\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\sin{x}dx=\frac{4}{\pi}.$$

Which is correct. However, in the solution example, they just set $L=\pi$ and solve

$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int\limits_0^\pi\sin(x)dx=\frac{4}{\pi}.$$ How can they just set $L$ to $\pi$ if the formula says that if $f$ has a period $P$ then $P=2L?$

Comment: Maybe they are not setting $L = \pi$, but rather observing that if $f$ is $\pi$-periodic, then $$\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2} f(x) dx = \int^{a+\pi/2}_{a-\pi/2} f(x) dx$$ for any $a \in \mathbb R$. Choosing $a = \pi/2$, we see $$\int^{\pi/2}_{-\pi/2} \lvert \sin(x)\rvert dx = \int^\pi_0 \lvert \sin(x) \rvert dx = \int^\pi_0 \sin(x) dx,$$ since $\sin(x)$ is non-negative in that range.

Comment: That makes perfect sense. Maybe post it as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Actually, they specifically write out that $L=\pi,$ so they are setting it. Check this: http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~jdg/AE2SOLN.PDF

Comment: In this case, it seems like they are making a $2\pi$-periodic extension of the function. Of course, there is no problem doing this since the function is $\pi$-periodic, it is also $k\pi$-periodic for any $k=2,3,4,\ldots$, and as you've noticed, you'll get the same answer. When deriving the Fourier series, you consider extending the function periodically from $(-L,L)$ to $\mathbb R$, so here $L = \pi$, even though, as you've stated, the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$ contains two periods of the function.